# Array in documents not being mapped into list in java pojo object

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, pojo

I have the following mapping pojos in java

```
@Document(collection = "agency")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class AgentInformation implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private String _id;
    private List<Agent> agent 
     public String get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void set_id(String _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public List<Agent> getAgent() {
        return agent;
    }

    public void setAgent(List<Agent> agent) {
        this.agent = agent;
    }
}


public class Agent {
    private String name;
    public String getName() {return name;}
    public void setName(String name){this.name = name;}
}
```

Mongodb document looks like so on compass:

```
  _id: "fdfddf99df9df";
  agent : Array
       0: Object
          name: "eduardo"
```

This is the statement I execute in java to get all the documents:

```
mongoTemplate.findAll(AgentInformation.class);
```

id is mapped but array is not mapped. What am I missing?

Comment: Argument is simple.  in compass you get name `prinAgent`. But the array you named in pojo is `agent`. Either you can have same in both places, or you need to map

Comment: That was a typo sorry.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't check fully AgentInformation.class. The actual problem is you didn't map what is agent. You may need `@DBRef` or aggregation to join both collections. Normally spring data doesn't do association if there is no anotation `@DBRef`

Comment: `mongoTemplate.findAll(AgentInformation.class);` - what is the output you are getting? The `findAll` returns a `List<AgentInformation>` - print the list elements.

Comment: I get all the IDs but not the agent lists.

Comment: Still not working? @Fernando